Prevent Oracle Dbms_XmlDom from escaping attributes
Another question about Oracle's Dbms_XmlDom functionality. This time about setting attributes.
Here's the code:
DECLARE
   doc_   dbms_XmlDom.DomDocument := Dbms_XmlDom.newDomDocument;
   nd_    dbms_XmlDom.DomNode;
   tag_   dbms_XmlDom.DomElement;
   data_in_ VARCHAR2(50) := '&#163;';
   out_   VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN
   Dbms_XmlDom.setVersion (doc_, '1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes');
   tag_ := Dbms_XmlDom.createElement (
      doc     => doc_,
      tagName => 'coreProperties'
   );
   Dbms_XmlDom.setAttribute(tag_, 'myAttribute', data_in_);
   nd_  := Dbms_XmlDom.appendChild (Dbms_XmlDom.makeNode(doc_), Dbms_XmlDom.makeNode(tag_));

   out_ := Dbms_XmlDom.getXmlType(doc_).getClobVal;
   Dbms_XmlDom.freeDocument (doc_);
   Dbms_Output.Put_Line (out_);
END;

And here's the output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<coreProperties myAttribute="&amp;#163;"/>

I need the output to be:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<coreProperties myAttribute="&#163;"/>

In other words, I want to prevent the & in the input data (which gets fed into the attribute's value) from escaping into &amp; by the function setAttribute(). Can it be done?
I should add that if this were data being fed into an element, I could CDATA it. But this can't be done in attributes, I believe.

The direct answer to this question seems to be a "no".  It's not possible to inform Dbms_XmlDom that some & characters are themselves part of an escaped character-sequence and therefore should not themselves be escaped.
However, my original question was a little unfair in that it didn't give a full context of why this was necessary.  I didn't think any further context was necessary at the time.
The full story is that my overall PL/SQL program is building an Excel file and to encapsulate the functionality that I need, I need to encode the cell's format mask like the following (rendering the cell a in UK currency format):
_-£* #,##0.00_-;\£* #,##0.00_-

Unfortunately, when you put that exact format into an XML tag like this
<numFmt numFmtId="48" formatCode="_-£* #,##0.00_-;\£* #,##0.00_-"/>

Excel complains of corruption because for whatever reason, Excel doesn't accept £ as an attribute to an XML node.
A work around that Excel does accept an escaped version of £ into an XML attribute, like this:
<numFmt numFmtId="48" formatCode="_-&#163;* #,##0.00_-;\&#163;* #,##0.00_-"/>

Essentially therefore, we load £ into an XML file with its HTML escape-sequence.  The problem I had was that this XML is being generated by code which itself escapes the & character in &#163;, causing my output XML to look like:
<numFmt numFmtId="48" formatCode="_-&amp;#163;* #,##0.00_-;\&amp;#163;* #,##0.00_-"/>

So I have a case of a doubly escaped escape-sequence (which again causes an Excel file corruption).
The solution I found (after taking a step back) is that Excel also accepts different ways of encoding £.  Essentially, it accepts £ if it is enclosed in an escaped instance of quote " (such as "£").  So, this XML is accepted by Excel.
<numFmt numFmtId="48" formatCode="_-&quot;£&quot* #,##0.00_-;\&quot;£&quot;* #,##0.00_-"/>

And this can be encoded in Dmbs_XmlDom in this way:
DECLARE
   doc_   dbms_XmlDom.DomDocument := Dbms_XmlDom.newDomDocument;
   nd_    dbms_XmlDom.DomNode;
   tag_   dbms_XmlDom.DomElement;
   data_in_ VARCHAR2(50) := '"£"'; -- plus the rest of the currency mask, of course
   out_   VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN
   Dbms_XmlDom.setVersion (doc_, '1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes');
   tag_ := Dbms_XmlDom.createElement (doc_, 'coreProperties');
   Dbms_XmlDom.setAttribute(tag_, 'myAttribute', data_in_);
   nd_  := Dbms_XmlDom.appendChild (Dbms_XmlDom.makeNode(doc_), Dbms_XmlDom.makeNode(tag_));

   out_ := Dbms_XmlDom.getXmlType(doc_).getClobVal;
   Dbms_XmlDom.freeDocument (doc_);
   Dbms_Output.Put_Line (out_);
END;

Thanks to @MTO for his/her help.  Their answer forced me to rethink the escape sequences used in XML and look at other alternatives that Excel might accept.

A partial answer (that solves the issue of DBMS_XMLDOM escaping the ampersand in something that is already escaped) is to unescape the HTML codes and then let DBMS_XMLDOM.SETATTRIBUTE escape only those characters that actually need escaping:
DECLARE
   doc_   dbms_XmlDom.DomDocument := Dbms_XmlDom.newDomDocument;
   nd_    dbms_XmlDom.DomNode;
   tag_   dbms_XmlDom.DomElement;
   data_in_ VARCHAR2(50) := UTL_I18N.unescape_reference('&#163;&eacute;&amp;');
   out_   VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN
   Dbms_XmlDom.setVersion (doc_, '1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes');
   tag_ := Dbms_XmlDom.createElement (
      doc     => doc_,
      tagName => 'coreProperties'
   );
   Dbms_XmlDom.setAttribute(tag_, 'myAttribute', data_in_);
   nd_  := Dbms_XmlDom.appendChild (Dbms_XmlDom.makeNode(doc_), Dbms_XmlDom.makeNode(tag_));

   out_ := Dbms_XmlDom.getXmlType(doc_).getClobVal;
   Dbms_XmlDom.freeDocument (doc_);
   Dbms_Output.Put_Line (out_);
END;
/

Outputs:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<coreProperties myAttribute="£é&amp;"/>


Which outputs &#163; as £ and &eacute; as é because they do not need escaping and &amp; as &amp; because it does actually need escaping.
However, this doesn't quite get your expected output - but it does solve the problem you wanted to solve with a slightly different solution.

Nice try. Well done for spotting that &#163; is the escape sequence for £.  Nevertheless, it doesn't quite work. The £ sign itself doesn't get escaped by Dbms_XmlDom, and so if I "just" wanted to put a £ sign in the XML attribute, I could just simply write this: Dbms_XmlDom.setAttribute(tag_, 'myAttribute', '£');.  The point of the question is that the application which consumes the XML (Excel actually) doesn't understand a raw £ symbol. Hence, I have to pass £ as an escape-sequence so that Excel decodes the sequence and converts it back to £.

@cartbeforehorse If you look at the answer, this uses UTL_I18N.unescape_reference to convert from the escaped string to an unescaped string. Pass your escaped string &#163; from Excel to Oracle, unescape it in Oracle using UTL_I18N.unescape_reference (which returns £) and pass the unescaped string to Dbms_XmlDom.setAttribute which then outputs <coreProperties myAttribute="£"/> which gives you the desired value (just unescaped rather than escaped <coreProperties myAttribute="&#163;"/>).

I did understand. I'm not receiving this data from Excel.  I'm using this data to build an XML file which itself is a sub-"part" of an Excel file output.  If I pass £ into the XML, Excel doesn't know how to read it and complains of corruption. If you pass &#163; instead, Excel no longer complains of corruption.  Your answer has been helpful though.  It helped me find a viable solution.  It's just that your answer in an of itself wasn't correct.
